# Why is the pdf I'm extracting from Word via office.js corrupted?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, office365, office-js

I'm using the demo code (mostly) found [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync) to pull a pdf out of a word document on Office365.

When I send the file to a basic ruby controller (that just saves it to a tmp file so I can examine it), I'm able to open the pdf, but all the pages are blank.  I tried encoding / decoding to base64 but then it was unopenable.

Here is the salient JS code, what executes once I have all the slices of the file stored in the docdataSlices array:

What am I missing?  Any help mucho appreciated.

```
function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var docdata = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
    docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
  }

  var fileContent = new String();
  for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
    //fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
    // base 64 encode
    fileContent += window.btoa(docdata[j]);
  }

  // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
  // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...

  // Send the file as the body of an HTTP POST
  // request to the web server.
  request.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/files");
  request.send(fileContent);

  console.log('got the whole file!');
}
```

And here is the code in my vanilla rails controller to simply save the file:

```
require 'base64'

class FilesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    decoded_base64_content = Base64.decode64(request.body.read)
    tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/addin.pdf"
    File.open(tmp_file, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write decoded_base64_content
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

Comment: When, instead of sending your generated PDF file to a web server, you save that file to disk, is the file you saved to disk also corrupted?

Comment: I didn't even know javascript could write to local storage.  Let me look into that, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I don't know that JS can write to local storage--I read too quickly and didn't see that the PDF was being generated in JS.  I apologize for the probably useless suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you used getFileAsync()? You may also want to take a look at this example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-SliceDataChunks